# What is the answer of: 6÷2(1+2) =?

Tags: java, math

I have this debate, whether the answer of 6÷2(1+2) is 9 or 1.

```
public class bodmas
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    float i = 6/2*(1+2);
    System.out.println(i);
}

}
```

**Java returns 9**, but that's because I cannot remove the * sign. If I put this into my Casio fx-82MS calculator it returns 9 if I insert **6/2*(1+2)** but 1 if I insert **6/2(1+2)**

This worries me as a Java Developer because if the answer is really different, we have a problem. I have tried it on different versions of calculators, the answer gives out 9, however on mine it gives out 1. So probably there's nothing to worry about.

As a **Conclusion**, the question is ambiguous and in programming terms it would return 9. If it had to return 1, a more clear question would be 6/(2*(1+2)) .

Comment: I'm going for 1, but I've got an economics degree so I should be considered an unreliable source.

Comment: [Google says 9](http://www.google.ca/search?q=6%2F2%281%2B2%29)

Comment: No need for the downvote... This is a genuine math vs java question

Comment: @Scobal: [No, it's not](https://www.facebook.com/home.php?sk=question&id=1967593674538&qa_ref=qd).

Comment: I'm not convinced that any of the 5 people that closed this question actually read it... They probably just looked at the title

Comment: @Scobal: I'm not convinced that you looked at my link either... :(

Comment: @Mehrdad: What does that have to do with the java code in the question?

Comment: @Mehrdad: I missed your link first time around :) too quick

Comment: No need to downvote, because I tried this question in Java, so yes it's a Stack Overflow question, and yes this worries me, because if the answer is really 1, Java returns 9.

Comment: @Ryan: Do you *really* have no idea what the answer is? AFAIK basic arithmetic is a prerequisite to all programming courses I've seen...

Comment: The answer to the question, "What is 6/2(1+2)?" in almost every computer language I know is "syntax error". But assuming we add the "*", what you're asking about is operator precedence. In Java (and most other computer languages), multiply and divide have equal precedence, above plus or minus, and within each evaluation is left to right. The parentheses around the 1+2 make that happen first. Then the / and the * happen left to right, first we do the 6/2, then we do the *. Answer is 9. To get 1 you would have to change the order with parentheses, i.e. "6/(2*(1+2))".

Comment: Take it from a professional mathematician: no one should care, and it doesn't matter in the slightest.  Go find something *important* to worry about instead.  Oh, and the answer is 9; multiplication and division have equal precedence and are left-associative.

Comment: @Ryan: Well, just because you typed it into Java doesn't make it a Java question. I could write a Java program reading "String s=What is the secret to happiness in life?" Unfortunately, the answer to that, too, would be "syntax error". :-)

Comment: @Jay it can be an issue when you have an algorithm or a formula and a * in between a number and a brackets make a difference in the value.

Comment: @Ryan: No it does not. If you're converting the math formula to code, then no matter what the language, _as long as it follows the operator precedence_, it should give you 9. For example, mathematica does not require a `*` in between. The multiplication is automatically implied, but a `*` can be included too. Both `6/2 (1 + 2)` and `6/2 * (1 + 2)` return the same value, `9`. Your calculator probably includes `()` automatically when it shouldn't be doing so.

Comment: @yoda thanks then, yes the answer from my calculator was worrying me

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's simple mathematics question not related to programming itself

Comment: @StephenCanon, Why should no one care? We should all care if it's leading to wrong answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on how you define your representation.  In Java (indeed, in most languages):

```
6 / 2 * (1+2)
```

is equivalent to

```
(6 / 2) * (1+2)
```

which is 9.

Your calculator is interpreting it as:

```
6 / (2 * (1+2))
```

which is indeed 1.

Comment: 6/2 = 3. 1+2 = 3. That's where 9 comes from.

Comment: @Oli exactly, and this worries me, because as a programmer, you cannot use 6/2(1+2) in Java, but you have to use 6/2*(1+2) which give different answers

Comment: @Ryan: Yes, because 6/2(1+2) is ambiguous.  I would have trouble working out what the intention was if you wrote it on paper for me.

Comment: I think there's an informal assumption among humans that the implicit, omitted * has higher precedence than an explicit * -- it acts like an implicit *-plus-parens....

Comment: @Michael Petrotta - Yes mate I noticed, sorry for my mistake

Comment: @jwismar No idea where you get that notion from, at least I've never heart of it. Multiplication and division have the same precedence and are left associative - that's all there is to it.

Comment: @Voo really?! I think most people would interpret ((x)->6/2x)(3) as 1. I think we could find 2x as the lazy form of (2*x) in many texts.

Comment: I'm not saying it's even vaguely correct, but I have a very hard time looking at a/bc and performing (a/b)c, even though I know the rules. And if I meant to do the division first, I would not choose to write it as a/bc, but rather as (a/b)c or a/b*c, because I find the effect so compelling. This is one of the reasons that in code reviews I often recommend using parens even when they're unnecessary, rather than relying on operation precedence, because although the compiler always does what's correct, people looking at it can easily misinterpret what the result ought to be.

Answer (score 10):

According to [Order of Operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) the answer should be 9.

Comment: This very example is mentioned there!

Comment: Parentheses is evaluated first, and after that If an expression contains more than one operator with the same precedence level (multiplication, division), the operators are performed in left-to-right order both in math and many programming languages. 


6 / 2 * 3

Answer (score 0):

omg guys.
Ask youself: What is 
a ÷ a = ?  It is ONE.
Now think of Itentity Law: a = 1a = 1(a)
now ask what is
a ÷ 1a = ?  Obviously 1 !! a ÷ 1a != a ÷ 1 * a 
What is a ÷ 2a ?  Ans: 1/2
What is 6 ÷ 2a ? Ans: 3/a
Let a = 1+2 in all of the above.
Stop converting stuff like 2a = 2 * a. It is 2a = (2 * a)

Comment: `What is a ÷ a = ? It is ONE` ok google, 0 ÷ 0 != 1 )))

Answer (score 0):

I am amused by the com "9 is super wrong, you just break the laws of algebra" while they themselves forget that the parentheses are done first

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).